# Getting all data between 2 days in MySql Java

Tags: java, mysql, swing

I want to select all data from database table between given 2 specific dates and add that data to a jtable.

Below is my code to retrieve data from the database; But all the data is not shown by this code .. What is the error I done here?

```
private void updateTable(){
    String fday = ((JTextField)day_chooser.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText();
    String tday = ((JTextField)day_chooser.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText();
    try {
        String sql = "SELECT *  FROM saleinfo WHERE SaleDate BETWEEN '"+fday+"' AND '"+tday+"'";
        pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs=pst.executeQuery();
        tbl.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));


    } catch (Exception ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error : "+ex);
    }

}
```

Comment: 1. Don't get the text from the text component, get the `Date` from the date component `day_chooser.getDate()` - also, the value will be the same, since you're using the same component; 2. Use a `PreapredStatement`, see [Using Prepared Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) for more details.  Bind the `Date` value from the date picker to the columns directly, `pst.setDate(new java.sql.Date(fDay.getTime());`, etc...

Comment: Remember, Java has a concept of "time" and so does MySQL, these concepts may not be the same thing

Comment: I used your 1 method above. But not showing any result in the table. I'm using prepared statements `pst` is the prepare statement @MadProgrammer

Comment: make sure when mysql gets is, it looks like '2015-08-23'

Comment: *"pst is the prepare statement"* BUT, you're not using it properly!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leverage the JDBC drive and it's ability to map between data types from Java to the database, leverage the power of the `PreparedStatement`

> I'm using prepared statements pst is the prepare statement

BUT, you're not using it properly, see [Using Prepared Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) for more details.

Start by getting the `Date` value from the date picker (I'm guessing here, but I assume they have some kind of `getDate` method) and then bind the values to the wildcard columns of the query, for example...

```
Date fday = day_chooser.getDate();
Date tday = day_chooser.getDate();
try {
    String sql = "SELECT *  FROM saleinfo WHERE SaleDate BETWEEN ? AND ?";
    try (PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
        pst.setDate(1, new java.sql.Date(fday.getTime()));
        pst.setDate(2, new java.sql.Date(tday.getTime()));
        try (ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery()) {
            tbl.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
        }
    }
} catch (Exception ex) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error : " + ex);
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Don't assume anything about the format, this will just cause you no end of grieve if you ever have to change databases